# Error: bulkCopyToSqlDB is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Using the following link to load data to SQL DB from Databricks I'm getting the following error:

`command-3227900948916301:23: error: value bulkCopyToSqlDB is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)`

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/blob/fa1cf19ed797648a20d9b7f474d7c2cd88829ada/samples/scripts/BulkCopySample.scala

My code is as follows:

```
val bulkCopyConfig  = Config(Map(
  "url"          -> url,
  "databaseName" -> databaseName,
  "dbTable"      -> "dbo.xxxx",
  "user"         -> user,
  "password"     -> password,
  "connectTimeout" -> "120",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "100000",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "0",
  "truncate" -> "true"
//  "queryTimeout"   -> "5"
))

//~

df. write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have correct imports to extend the DataFrame with additional functions:

```scala
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._
```

here is what I get (it fails because I don't have active SQL DB, but it found the function):

```
scala> import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config

scala> import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

scala> val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
     |   "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
     |   "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
     |   "user"              -> "username",
     |   "password"          -> "*********",
     |   "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
     |   "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
     |   "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2500",
     |   "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
     |   "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
     | ))
bulkCopyConfig: com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config = com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.ConfigBuilder$$anon$1@754443e1

scala> val df = spark.range(1,10)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
20/10/06 16:24:38 ERROR DataFrameFunctions: Connection cannot be established to the database
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'username'. ClientConnectionId:b35aa6bb-24ec-4727-98b6-074cae4e6a32
...
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for reaching out. I haven't tried your solution yet, but it looks amazing.I will try it out later today. In the meantime thanks man